# Polyfill for TextDecoder

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, polyfills

I'm using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and have included the [`whatwg-fetch` polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch) in my application.

I also employ [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder) as described in Jake Archibald's blog [That's so fetch!](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/) to decode the response, but I'm not sure what polyfill to use.

(Currently Safari complains about `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TextDecoder`)

I'm guessing there's a polyfill for `TextDecoder`, but I'm not finding it...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using the [`text-encoding`](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding) library

```
npm install text-encoding --save
```

along with

```
import encoding from 'text-encoding';
const decoder = new encoding.TextDecoder();
```

Comment: just for decode which file I should add?  encoding.js or encoding-indexes.js??after adding is it necessary to use "import encoding from 'text-encoding';" this line??

Comment: HOLY SH*T! That's [536
kB](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=text-encoding@0.7.0) of needless bloat. For a much superior solution, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59188359/5601591 . The usage is the exact same: `import encoding from 'fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder';`, but there is no bloat whatsoever.

Answer (score 8):

Nowadays you can use the [FastestSmallestTextEncoderDecoder](https://github.com/anonyco/FastestSmallestTextEncoderDecoder) polyfill (1.5 KB), as recommended by the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder).

Answer (score 7):

For quick client-side testing (without NPM):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/text-encoding@0.6.4/lib/encoding-indexes.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/text-encoding@0.6.4/lib/encoding.js"></script>
```

..and then use `TextDecoder` like normal. [MDN's example:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder)

```js
var win1251decoder = new TextDecoder('windows-1251');
var bytes = new Uint8Array([207, 240, 232, 226, 229, 242, 44, 32, 236, 232, 240, 33]);
console.log(win1251decoder.decode(bytes)); // Привет, мир!
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/text-encoding@0.6.4/lib/encoding-indexes.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/text-encoding@0.6.4/lib/encoding.js"></script>
```

Comment: Instead i downloaded these scripts to my local folder and added to index.html like this  <script src="./js/encoding.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/object-assign-auto.js"></script>

Answer (score -1):

If all you want is to decode the array to utf8 simply add a function, no need of external libraries:

```
     function Utf8ArrayToStr(array) {
        var out, i, len, c;
        var char2, char3;

        out = "";
        len = array.length;
        i = 0;
        while(i < len) {
            c = array[i++];
            switch(c >> 4)
            {
                case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7:
                // 0xxxxxxx
                out += String.fromCharCode(c);
                break;
                case 12: case 13:
                // 110x xxxx   10xx xxxx
                char2 = array[i++];
                out += String.fromCharCode(((c & 0x1F) << 6) | (char2 & 0x3F));
                break;
                case 14:
                    // 1110 xxxx  10xx xxxx  10xx xxxx
                    char2 = array[i++];
                    char3 = array[i++];
                    out += String.fromCharCode(((c & 0x0F) << 12) |
                        ((char2 & 0x3F) << 6) |
                        ((char3 & 0x3F) << 0));
                    break;
            }
        }

        return out;
    }
```

Comment: Does not work with 4-byte sequences like `[0xF0,0x90,0x8D,0x88]`, which should yield ``.