# Webpack 5 Polyfill Node util.TextDecoder

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I have been at this for days (months if you really want to be technical). Before someone marks this as a duplicate, no, I don't want to use the ~530kb `text-encoder` package, noted on the thread [Polyfill for TextDecoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662142). Additionally, `fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder` does not seem to have TypeScript types and will not compile.

I am trying to make my VS Code extension compatible with the web environment of VS Code, meaning I need to create two bundles using Webpack (client and web extensions differ slightly).

In one of my source files, `cheatsheet-content.ts`:

```js
import { TextDecoder } from 'util';

// ...

const htmlDocument = await vscode.workspace.fs
    .readFile(
        vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._cheatsheetUri, 'cheatsheet.html')
    )
    .then((uint8array) => {
        const fileContent = new TextDecoder().decode(uint8array);  // <-- ERROR
        return parse(fileContent.toString());
    });
```

I get the error (only when running as a web extension): `TypeError: util_1.TextDecoder is not a constructor`.

Here is my `webpack.config.ts` file:

```js
/// <reference types="node" />

import * as path from 'node:path';
import { Configuration, ProvidePlugin } from 'webpack';

// eslint-disable-next-line unicorn/prefer-module
const projectRoot = __dirname;

const nodeConfig: Configuration = {
    // VS Code client extensions run in Node context. See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/
    target: 'node',
    // Leaves the source code as close as possible to the original (when packaging we set this to 'production')
    mode: 'none',
    // Entry point into extension (in package.json). See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
    entry: {
        'extension.node': './src/extension.node.ts',
    },
    // Bundle output location. See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.join(projectRoot, 'dist'),
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '../[resource-path]',
    },
    devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
    // Support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files. See: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        alias: {
            src: path.resolve(projectRoot, 'src'),
        },
    },
    // Modules that cannot be added through Webpack. See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
    externals: {
        vscode: 'commonjs vscode', // ignored because 'vscode' module is created on the fly and doesn't really exist
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false,
    },
    infrastructureLogging: {
        level: 'log', // enables logging required for problem matchers
    },
};

const browserConfig: Configuration = {
    // extensions run in a webworker context
    ...nodeConfig,
    target: 'webworker',
    entry: {
        'extension.web': './src/extension.web.ts',
        // 'test/suite/index': './src/web/test/suite/index.ts',
    },
    resolve: {
        ...nodeConfig.resolve,
        mainFields: ['browser', 'module', 'main'], // look for `browser` entry point in imported node modules
        fallback: {
            // eslint-disable-next-line unicorn/prefer-module
            util: require.resolve('util'),  // <-- Isn't this supposed to fix my issue?
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        new ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser', // provide a shim for the global `process` variable
        }),
    ],
};

// eslint-disable-next-line unicorn/prefer-module
module.exports = [nodeConfig, browserConfig];
```

I would have thought adding `util` to `resolve.fallback` would have fixed the issue, but I guess not?

I also tried using `node-polyfill-webpack-plugin`, but it didn't work, and it made a big fuss about `esModuleInterop`.

[Permalink](https://github.com/Antyos/vscode-openscad/tree/852e5dcb81) to my GitHub repo for full context. If you are interested in running the code yourself:

1. Clone the repo
2. Run `npm ci`
3. Go to **Run & Debug** in VS Code and select the `Run Web Extension` configuration
4. Open the command palette and run `OpenSCAD: Open Cheatsheet` command.

I know very little about Webpack besides that it is very confusing. Can anyone please provide any guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there is no need to polyfill `TextDecoder`, because it is part of globals for Node 16 and modern browsers. The import statement below can be removed, and everything works fine.

```js
// import { TextDecoder } from 'util';  // <-- REMOVE ME

// ...

const htmlDocument = await vscode.workspace.fs
    .readFile(
        vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._cheatsheetUri, 'cheatsheet.html')
    )
    .then((uint8array) => {
        const fileContent = new TextDecoder().decode(uint8array);
        return parse(fileContent.toString());
    });
```

See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/165#discussioncomment-3880268